# How can I add the contenteditable attribute and save the state of content editing on my posts/pages?

Tags: wordpress, frontend, contenteditable, savechanges

I am making my WordPress theme and what I want to do is to make use edit the page using front end editing means

I have to make a button on my post/pages my own custom button naming front editor using this line of code

```
add_action('media_buttons', 'add_my_custom_button');

function add_my_custom_button(){
    $post = get_the_id();    
    echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" class="button button-primary">Front Editor</a>';
}
```

**Now what I want to do**

1. on click of this button the button takes to the post/page link I want to add the contenteditable to true and a save button so the user can edit the page he/she can change the text content and
2. want to save the changes.

Here is my screenshot of button

[image]

How can I achieve that?